# Opencart module modification for the place it is used in the catalog

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

I have a module for Advanced Reviews.

By default you know the modules can be set to show up [in a specific page] in the following positions:

```
content_top
content_bottom
content_left
content_right
```

I want to show it under one of the product page's tab (Review Tab), thus I have added the following option to the above positions:

```
content_tab
```

But I don't know how should I enable it to show under the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create such position on the forntend as well. That means copying out and modifying of e.g. `content_top` (controller and template) into e.g. `content_tab`, then adding this new position as a child module to the controllers that may render it and finally render this position in respective templates on desired place (look how `content_top` is populated and rendered to have an idea).

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a position you don't use on your product page, you could just move the content into the tab on your `product.tpl` file. This wouldn't have any effect on any other page, so there's no risk of damaging other pages with it.

For example, if you don't use the right column position in your template, you could just edit your tpl and move `<?php echo $column_right; ?>` into the necessary location. Creating a new position will require **a lot** of extra work for this single tab content position

Comment: +1 Interesting, haven't thought about such solution.